# How to prevent openning a popup when you choose a layer to show in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, popup, google-maps-markers

I'm a working on a project with leaflet where a it shows three layer

[image]

you can enable o disable whenever you want to display all the markers from that layer.
Every marker has a popup that it opens when you click on the marker

The problema i have is that when you hit over on any layer and active it, the marker displays its popup.

[image]

Is there any way to not open it when you activate a layer? o at least to keep it close and just open when you click on it?

Thanks colleagues!

Answer (score 0):

I revised the solution to instead target layer activation.

This will programmatically unbind popup from each marker in the layer, hence preventing popups from opening when layer is activated.

```
var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

layerGroup.on("layeradd", function (event) {
  event.layer.eachLayer(function (marker) {
    marker.unbindPopup();
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering, your solution is so interesting but it didn't work for me. The popup works for mouseover and mouseout however when i hit on any layer to active it, the popup opens automatically :(

Comment: Try the updated solution and let me know.